# What if data: is not used when submitting a form?

Tags: jquery

When submitting a form using post, what if I dont want it serialized (or going as a string, which i feel is not safe) and want it to be submitted the same way as it would be if I wasn't using jquery? How could I do that?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#sform").serialize(), //don't want to use this part. Want it go just like it would without using jquery
```

Is this data: something that "has to be" used? What are the alternatives to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and want it to be submitted the same way as it would be if I wasn't using jquery?

That's exactly what the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method does :-) It formats the form data using [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) encoding which is the default format for html forms. So if you want the server to receive the data in **exactly the same format** as if you were not using javascript, then use the `.serialize()` method.

The standard method to AJAXify a form is the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sform').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
};
```

Now whether the user has javascript disabled or not, the server will receive the form POST in exactly the same way.